# Find something in long method (Intellij idea IDE)

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts, intellij-plugin, intellij-14

It is possible to find something in the method, and ignore everything outside of this scope.

Example: I have a looooooooong method (I know it is better to refactor it in many smaller pieces, but question not about that - as it is not my code and it is not covered by unit tests at all) .Now I want to decrease search scope to the current method (50-150 lines)

Is it possible?

Comment: Find in selection? Not super convenient but still...

Answer (score 3):

There is a feature request, not implemented yet, try upvoting:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-138365